# How to write addition and multiplication tables for a given modulus

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

As the question stated above:

> How to write addition and multiplication tables for a given modulus

Is this the right type of question? or else if it's not right category. Would you mind giving some sample questions and solution,please?

mod 4 
question 9 (mod 4)
solution :

```
       [0] [1] [2] [3]

       [4] [5] [6] [7]

       [8] [9] [10] [11]
```

the answer: 9(mod4)
            [1],[5],[9],...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like in grade school arithmetic, a table should simply be a chart where one can find out what a*b is by looking at the cell in the a column and the b row.

So draw a chart like this

```
+   |    0   |    1    |    2    |    3     
========================================
0   |0+0mod4 |0+1mod4  |0+ 2mod4 |0+3mod4
=========================================
1   |1+0mod4 |1+1mod4  |1+2mod4  |1+3mod4
=========================================
2   |2+0mod4 |2+1mod4  |2+2mod4  |2+3mod4
=========================================
3   |3+0mod4 |3+1mod4  |3+2mod4  |3+3mod4
```

only with the actual values in the cells.

=======

I'll get you started:

```
+   |    0   |    1    |    2    |    3     
========================================
0   |0+0mod4 |0+1mod4  |0+ 2mod4 |0+3mod4
=========================================
1   |1+0mod4 |1+1mod4  |1+2mod4  |1+3mod4
=========================================
2   |2+0mod4 |   3     |2+2mod4  |2+3mod4
=========================================
3   |3+0mod4 |3+1mod4  |   1     |3+3mod4
```

Because 1 + 2 = 3 mod(4) and 2 + 3 = 1 mod(4).

Comment: thank you!  so a,for example,is equal to 0 ; b is equal to 1 , correct?

Comment: b?  So if 1 + 2 = 3 mod 4, you'd put 3 is the 1,2 cell.  If 2+3 = 1 mod 4, you'd put 1 in the 2,3 cell.

Comment: is it the same with multiplication?

Comment: All they are asking is to list all possible a+b mod 4 and all possible a\*b mod 4 and to put them is a square table so the values can be looked.  There are only sixteen combinations of each so just fill them in.  Of course, you have to figure out, for example, what *is* 3*2 mod  4.  four hints.  i) both addition and multiplication are commutative (a*b = b*a) so that two tables with be symmetric across the diagonal (the a,b cell will be the same as the b,a cell).  ii) 0 + a = a + 0 = a, so the 0 row and column are just the header line and column.

Comment: ...iii) Same thing with 1 x a = a x 1 = a.  iv) 0 x a = a x 0 = 0, so in the multiplication table the 0 row and column will be all 0.

Answer (score 0):

So, each column is the *equivalence class* of integers whose remainder is the integer in the first row of the same column — that is, the columns are the congruence classes.

Here are two (very) useful facts about modular arithmetic, which you might want to either prove, or at least verify with several concrete examples:

> For all integers $a,b,c,d\ge 0$, for $n>1$,
>
> - $a \equiv c \pmod n$ and $b \equiv d \pmod n \implies (a+b) \equiv (c+d)\pmod n$
> - $a \equiv c \pmod n$ and $b \equiv d \pmod n \implies ab \equiv cd\pmod n$

For example, $5 \equiv 1\pmod 4$, $10 \equiv 2\pmod 4$, so $15\equiv 3\pmod 4$, and $50 \equiv 2 \pmod 4$.

Comment: does concrete example means ,subtitute a number?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Another example mod 4: $7 \equiv 3\pmod 4$, $6 \equiv 2 \pmod 4$, so $13 \equiv 5 \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, and $42 \equiv 6 \equiv 2 \pmod 4. Now try some other bases -- say, mod 7, mod 10 (this should be very familiar & easy!), mod 12 (likewise -- clocks). Also, mod 2 (even and odd).